# how to make an ntfs case sensitive

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, case-sensitive

I'm wondering how to make an NTFS partition case sensitive in windows 7 ?
I don't want my whole system to be case sensitive, I only need one partition, or even better, one whole directory tree

The basic use I would have for it would be to host files that were stored on an ext3 file system and which filenames are case sensitive

Any idea or other approach ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to make NTFS case sensitive, it already is! Only the Win32 subsystem does not make use of that. From the Posix subsystem the file system is case sensitive, though.

More information: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100625

Comment: Windows 7 uses NT. All the document says is that it preserves the casing.  But there isn't an easy way to take full advantage of the casing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I gather from your answer that means if we are using an application compiled for win32, it may experience file collisions.

Comment: that MS Knowledge Base page appears to be no longer available and it's not clear how to find its current location if it exists